# Defer [super dealloc] call in a multi-step cleanup in Objective C (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it illegal in Objective-C to defer a call to `[super dealloc]` until some multi-step cleanup is complete, or must `[super dealloc]` always be called during `dealloc` (or not at all)?

For instance,

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
  // Pretend this returns immediately and results in a call
  // to OnAsynchronousShutdownProcessDone some time later:
  StartAsynchronousShutdownProcess(); 
}

- (void) OnAsynchronousShutdownProcessDone()
{
  // Let's assume the worst and pretend we might even be on
  // a different thread here.
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Is this allowed?  If not, what are some alternative approaches?

EDIT:  To provide some context, this involves shutting down an interaction with an external library that is targeting this object (as a void*, but all the same, referring to this).  Only once we get an "interaction finished" message do we know nothing else will be targeting this object.  In other words, there is a request/response involved in the shutdown.  There are probably many ways to do this, but if we can just defer the [super dealloc] until we've gotten that response from the external library, that would be simple.

Comment: It'd help if you could describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve. What are you cleaning up with this async process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is illegal in both possible cases:

- In ARC, you don't even specify when to call `[super dealloc]` anymore – the runtime manages it for you. You're forbidden from explicitly sending `-dealloc`, even to `super`.
- Outside of ARC, the documentation for `-[NSObject dealloc]` states:

> ...your implementation of dealloc must invoke the superclass’s implementation as its last instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, this is for non-ARC. I strongly believe you can't do that. It will very likely crash. Once the `dealloc` method enters, the runtime assumes, that there is no other (strong) reference which will send a message to it (from another thread).

In ARC you would use a weak pointer on the client library. Accessing the weak pointer at a time where the `dealloc` method has been invoked would return a `nil` value.

You are better of introducing some sort of `invalidate` method which gets invoked once the library won't need the object anymore. Then you can release the object within method `invalidate` which eventually deallocates the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
[super dealloc]
```

MUST be called during your dealloc method when using manual reference counting (not deferred) and must NOT be called at all when using ARC.

As soon as your dealloc method returns, the memory for the object is released, so an attempt to call [super dealloc] later would cause a crash.

In ARC code you're not supposed to call super [super dealloc] at all.